# Redirect to HTTPS doesn't include Request URI

Tags: php, .htaccess, acquia

In my `.htaccess` file I have added this general rule to redirect all non-secure requests to HTTPS. Works well until you type in a uri then it just directs you to the index page (with SSL).

Example: mysite.com is directed to https://www.mysite1.com works well, but mysite1.com/mypage is directed to https://www.mysite1.com the Request_uri is not included.

Here's the code I used:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This is a Drupal 8 site running on Acquia's Cloud.

Anyone have any clue what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out what i did wrong.
There was nothing wrong with the rules i wrote but where in the `.htaccess` file i put them.

I initially put them at the end of `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` section, after placing them just after the `Authorization HTTP header` inside the section it's working as expected